SelectFirst and Hold
Say I have a list of Hold elements. I use Hold because the operations are quite expensive (they are integrals).
I want to return first value that is greater than 5. If there is no such value, return the last one: SelectFirst[list, ReleaseHold[#]>5 &, 1].
The problem is that SelectFirst returns the Hold object. I can ReleaseHold, but the operation is running twice.
And how can I return the last evaluated element in the list as default?

I want to return the last evaluated item in the list.

Thanks. I misunderstood what the last line in the question meant.

You can use Reap and Sow. The below returns the held expression and it's evaluated result.
Using list from @RomaLee
list=Hold[Print["working for ", #, "s"]; Pause[#]; #]&/@Range@10

Then
mySelect[expr_List, crit_] :=
 With[{res = Reap[SelectFirst[expr, crit]]}
  , Switch[First[res],
   _Missing, {First@expr, {First@res[[-1, 1]]}},
   _, MapAt[Last, res, {-1, 1}]
   ]
  ]

and
mySelect[list, Sow[ReleaseHold[#]] > 5 &]


{Hold[Print["working for ", 6, "s"]; Pause[6]; 6], {6}}


and
mySelect[list, Sow[ReleaseHold[#]] > 200 &]


{Hold[Print["working for ", 1, "s"]; Pause[1]; 1], {1}}


Hope this helps.

What if I want to return the first evaluated element as default?

@PaulR Ah, missed that part. See update.

I might use Scan + Return:
Scan[
 If[# > 5, Return[#, Scan]] &@(*Echo@*)ReleaseHold@# &,
 Table[With[{k = k}, Hold@Integrate[x^k, {x, 0, 2}]], {k, 10}],
 {1}
 ]

(*  32/5  *)

(Uncomment Echo to see steps.)

I misunderstood the final requirement, "how can I return the last evaluated element in the list as default?"
Here's a Fold solution similar to Scan showing it returns the last value, the integral of $x^{10}$ or $2^{11}/11 \approx 186.18$, even though it is less than the cutoff for this example.
Fold[
 If[# > 250, (* cutoff *)
     Return[#, Fold], #] &@
   ReleaseHold@#2 &,
 0, (* ignored if value <= cutoff *)
 Table[With[{k = k}, Hold@Integrate[x^k, {x, 0, 2}]], {k, 10}]]

(*  2048/11  *)


Re: "How to return the first evaluated element of the list as default value...?" You'll have to save it, so some programming is needed. E.g. Module[{first, cutoff = 250},  Fold[   Function[{val, next},    If[! ValueQ[first],     first = ReleaseHold@val;     If[first > cutoff,      Return[val, Fold]]     ];    If[# > cutoff,       Return[#, Fold],       #       ] &@ReleaseHold[next];    first    ],   Table[With[{k = k}, Hold@Integrate[x^k, {x, 0, 2}]], {k, 10}]]  ]

Variation: Module[{iter, cutoff = 250, tag},  iter[val_, next_] := ( (* defines itself on first call *)    iter[First] = ReleaseHold@val;    If[iter[First] > cutoff,     Throw[iter[First], tag]];    iter[v_, n_] := ReleaseHold@n;    ReleaseHold@next);  Catch[   Fold[    Function[{val, next},     Replace[      iter[val, next],      v_ /; v > cutoff :> Throw[v, tag]      ];     iter[First]     ],    Table[With[{k = k}, Hold@Integrate[x^k, {x, 0, 2}]], {k, 10}]],   tag]  ]

You can use FirstCase with appropriate pattern:
list=Hold[Print["working for ", #, "s"]; Pause[#]; #] & /@ Range[10];(*imitation of time consuming calculations*)
FirstCase[list, _?((r = ReleaseHold[#]) > 5 &) :> r, 1] (*=> 6*)

Note that r variable is wasted here. So to avoid this you can wrap the code with Module[{r},...]:
Module[{r},FirstCase[list, _?((r = ReleaseHold[#]) > 5 &) :> r, 1]] (*=> 6*)


How to return the first evaluated element of the list as default value, i.e. when no element in the list satisfies the condition?

I would probably just introduce a temporary state variable:
Module[
  {temp}, 
  SelectFirst[inputs, (temp = ReleaseHold[#]) > 5 &]; 
  temp]

where inputs is your list of held expressions.

Using the list from @RomaLee
list=Hold[Print["working for ", #, "s"]; Pause[#]; #]&/@Range@10;


You can use FirstMatchingValue by Sjoerd Smit:
FirstMatchingValue = ResourceFunction["FirstMatchingValue"];

FirstMatchingValue[list, Hold[x_] :> With[{r = x}, r /; ReleaseHold[r] > 5]]


Or using FirstCase and same pattern:
FirstCase[list, Hold[x_] :> With[{r = x}, r /; ReleaseHold[r] > 5]]


Using With in this pattern-matching problem provides several advantages. Firstly, it avoids the hassle of having to manage external variable assignments (as when using Module), keeping the logic tidy. Second, ReleaseHold is evaluated exactly once per element, a real boon when you're dealing with computationally expensive operations.
Edit
Initially, I didn't account for including the default value, as I focused on achieving a straightforward solution with patterns using With. However, to handle the default case properly, the following modularization is necessary:
SelectFirstWithDefault[list_, rule_RuleDelayed, levelspec_ : {1}] := 
  Module[{lhs = rule[[1]], rhs = rule[[2]], matched}, 
   matched = 
    Last@Catch[
      Fold[If[MatchQ[#2, lhs], Throw[Append[#1, #2], "FoundPattern"], 
         Append[#1, #2]] &, {}, 
       Level[Unevaluated[list], levelspec, Unevaluated]], 
      "FoundPattern", Function[result, result /. rule]]];

list = Hold[Print["working for ", #, "s"]; Pause[#]; #] & /@ Range[4];

Case with a match:
SelectFirstWithDefault[list5, i_ /; ReleaseHold[i] > 2 :> Framed[i], {2}]


Case without a match:
SelectFirstWithDefault[list5, i_ /; ReleaseHold[i] > 5 :> Framed[i], {2}]


Additional examples for using SelectFirstWithDefault with de default levelspec:
SelectFirstWithDefault[{1, 1, f[a], 2, 3, y, f[8], 9, f[10]}, f[x_] :> x]

(*a*)

SelectFirstWithDefault[{a, 5/2, 6, 7, 8}, i_Integer :> i]

(*6*)

